# Use Jquery tablesorter to sort column displayed as mm/yyyy to sort in yyyymm order

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

Good afternoon all.

I have a table that has a column with dates displayed in mm/yyyy format. When I click a column, I would like column displayed in yyyymm ascending or descending order. I am using jquery tablesorter and have read where I could use a parser for this but can't seem to get the syntax.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you.

I have this in my external .js file:

```
 $("#adminInterestInformationTable").tablesorter({ headers: { 5: { sorter: "yyyymm" } } });

 var oTable = $("#adminInterestInformationTable").dataTable({
    //"sScrollY": tableHeight + "px",
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    //"oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": "No Public Assistance" },
    "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": "No Interest" },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "5px" },
        { "sWidth": "15px" },
        { "sWidth": "20px" },
        { "sWidth": "20px" },
        { "sWidth": "20px" },
        { "iDataSort": 7, "sWidth": "20px" },  //Override and Sort to the 8th column
        { "iDataSort": 8, "sWidth": "20px" },  //Override and Sort to the 9th column
        { "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "50px" },
        { "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "50px" }

    ]
});
```

Here is ASPX(InterestStartDate is column I want to sort on):

```
<table id="adminInterestInformationTable" class="leftNavTable" summary="List of all Interest">
<thead style="background: #0B649F; color: white">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type='checkbox' id="selectAllItems" alt="Select all inactive Interest" />
        </th>
        <th>IVD #
        </th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Interest Rate
        </th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Interest Type
        </th>
        <th>Sub Account
        </th>
        <th>Start Date
        </th>
        <th>End Date
        </th>


    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <asp:Repeater ID="InterestListRepeater" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
        OnItemCommand="InterestList_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="InterestList_OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="InterestRepeaterRow" runat="server">

                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="InterestRowCheckbox" name="paymentinterest"       value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PaymentInterestId") %>'
                        alt='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PaymentInterestId") %>'     runat="server" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="InterestSelectLinkButton" CausesValidation="false"     Style="display: none" runat="server"
                        Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval    (Container.DataItem, "PaymentInterestID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:Label ID="IVDNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CaseNumber")%>' />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                    <asp:Label ID="InterestRate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestPercent")%>' />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="InterestType" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestTypeDescription")%>' />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="SubAccount" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubAccountTypeCd")%>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="InterestStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestStartDate")%>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="InterestEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestEndDate")%>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="InterestStartDateSort" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestStartDateOriginal")%>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="InterestEndDateSort" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestEndDateOriginal")%>' />
                </td>
             </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The code you shared has code for both tablesorter and datatables... which one are you using (you can't use both)?

Comment: In the external .js file the "var otable" refers to table adminInterestInformationTable in the ASPX. There is a statement above this which says to sort the column as currency:

Comment: Didn't finish:      $("#adminInterestInformationTable").tablesorter ({ headers: { 0: { sorter: false }, 2: { sorter: "currency" } } });  I would like to do th seame thing for another column.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The variable `oTable` is attached to initialization code for DataTables (http://datatables.net/). I'm asking which jQuery plugin are you using? If you are using tablesorter, can you share the code you are using for the "yyyymm" parser.

Comment: Hi Mottie. I am using tablesorter. My question is, from reading it appears I need to use the parser to put the column(5) data in YYYYMM format prior to sorting. I am not sure how to do that. Bottom line, inside table in ASPX is repeater. Data displayed as MM/YYYY, when they click arrow in repeater the data sorts as if YYYYMM. Thanks you.

Comment: That should be Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/736/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "mmyyyy",
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        var date = s.split('/');
        if (date.length > 1) {
            return new Date(date[1], parseInt(date[0]) - 1).getTime();
        }
        return s;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        2: {
            sorter: 'mmyyyy'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wanted to search on 5th and 6th column(Start and End dates) so I changed table sorter to:

Comment: $('table').tablesorter({
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: false },
            2: { sorter: "currency" },
            5: { sorter: 'mmyyyy' },
            6: { sorter: 'mmyyyy' }
        }
    });  AND IT WORKS!!!! The add parser routine is cryptic, need to understand it more. Thank you Mottie!

Comment: Basically it takes the string, splits it at the `/` into an array. If an array exists, make it into a date. The second part has the year, the first part has the month (but we need it to be a zero-based index, so parse it and subtract one)... return the time in seconds so it is easier to compare to other cells.